# Error with [webpack-cli] : Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module

Tags: node.js, webpack-dev-server, es6-modules

a few days ago I received my new MacBook M2 and I have some problems.

When I try "npm run dev" after "npm install" successfully, this is displayed:

```
npm run dev           

> dev
> webpack serve --config ./bundler/webpack.dev.js

[webpack-cli] Failed to load '/Users/tombirembaut/Desktop/Resource Files/06-animations/bundler/webpack.dev.js' config
[webpack-cli] Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /Users/tombirembaut/node_modules/internal-ip/index.js from /Users/tombirembaut/Desktop/Resource Files/06-animations/bundler/webpack.dev.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /Users/tombirembaut/Desktop/Resource Files/06-animations/bundler/webpack.dev.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/tombirembaut/Desktop/Resource Files/06-animations/bundler/webpack.dev.js:3:12)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async WebpackCLI.tryRequireThenImport (/Users/tombirembaut/Desktop/Resource Files/06-animations/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:225:26)
    at async loadConfigByPath (/Users/tombirembaut/Desktop/Resource Files/06-animations/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:1325:27)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async WebpackCLI.loadConfig (/Users/tombirembaut/Desktop/Resource Files/06-animations/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:1375:35)
    at async WebpackCLI.createCompiler (/Users/tombirembaut/Desktop/Resource Files/06-animations/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:1643:22)
    at async Command.<anonymous> (/Users/tombirembaut/Desktop/Resource Files/06-animations/node_modules/@webpack-cli/serve/lib/index.js:82:30)
    at async Command.parseAsync (/Users/tombirembaut/Desktop/Resource Files/06-animations/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/commander/lib/command.js:916:5)
    at async Command.<anonymous> (/Users/tombirembaut/Desktop/Resource Files/06-animations/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:1292:13)
    at async Command.parseAsync (/Users/tombirembaut/Desktop/Resource Files/06-animations/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/commander/lib/command.js:916:5)
    at async WebpackCLI.run (/Users/tombirembaut/Desktop/Resource Files/06-animations/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:1296:9)
    at async runCLI (/Users/tombirembaut/Desktop/Resource Files/06-animations/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/bootstrap.js:9:9) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

I tried to uninstall node and reinstall it without success, if you have any ideas where it could come from I'm interested !

Comment: **Instead change the require of index.js in /Users/tombirembaut/Desktop/Resource Files/06-animations/bundler/webpack.dev.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.** You are using `require`    to load an es module.